# No scaling for different screen sizes in Eclipse Graphical Layout

Tags: android, layout, screen

I cant seem to be able to fit my app into multiple screens.
I dont have any images, just buttons and some text. I use "dp" for margins and width and "sp" for text, yet the views' size only shrinks on larger displays. Moreover, some of the lower buttons shift on Galaxy Nexus (4.65" and above).

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

X

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView android:id="@+id/disp_nums" android:textSize="64sp"
        android:layout_width="200dp" android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="center" android:text="1111" />

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText android:id="@+id/ent_nums" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Entered numbers" />

        <Button android:id="@+id/enter" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="0.37"
            android:text="Enter" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_marginTop="15dp">


        <Button android:id="@+id/button7" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="7" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button8" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="8" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button9" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="9" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button android:id="@+id/button4" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="4" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button5" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="5" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button6" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">



        <Button android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="2" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button3" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="40sp"
            android:text="3" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button android:id="@+id/delete" android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_marginRight="96dp"
            android:text="Del" android:textSize="12sp" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button0" android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
            android:text="0" android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Screens:

[Link1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bfu7w.jpg)

[Link2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuaO1.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Create folders

```
layout-small
layout-large
layout-xlarge
```

and

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-ldpi
```

you screen size are like that

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

and add permissions to your manifest

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

for more 
[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks!
One question though, I thought that by "scaling", everything will look the same on all devices. I mean, with proportion. My app seems to get smaller and smaller when I go on a bigger screen. Is it suppose to be like that?

Comment: Yeah, you've to adjust the layout and other things for each screen size folder.

Answer (score -1):

//use this for your last del and 0 layout.
its working for all devices and both mode landscape and portrait.

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
        <Button android:id="@+id/delete" android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
            android:text="Del" android:textSize="12sp" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/button0" android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/delete"
            android:text="0" android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That fixed the shift part, thank you!
One question though, I thought that by "scaling", everything will look the same on all devices. I mean, with proportion. My app seems to get smaller and smaller when I go on a bigger screen.